# Postgres/PostGIS is returning data from a table that doesn't exist (I'm a newbie -- show me why I am wrong)

Tags: postgresql, select, postgis

I am following a [tutorial for PostGIS](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/introduction.html). I have uploaded all the example datasets (all shapefiles) into a PostgreSQL database, although I have modified the names so they do not all match the names of those in the tutorial. I then ran the following code from the tutorial:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
  SELECT
  subways.name AS subway_name,
  neighborhoods.name AS neighborhood_name,
  neighborhoods.boroname AS borough
  FROM neighborhoods AS neighborhoods
  JOIN stations AS subways
  ON ST_Contains(neighborhoods.geom, subways.geom);''', engine)
```

This worked and returned the expected output. But when I went back through this query I noticed that the table "subways" was referenced (*maybe this is where I am confused*) but I don't have a table named "subways" because I had titled this table "stations". Indeed, here is the list of available tables in the db:

```
pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema = 'public';''',engine)

       table_name
   0   geography_columns
   1    geometry_columns
   2     spatial_ref_sys
   3       neighborhoods
   4      raster_columns
   5    raster_overviews
   6             streets
   7               solar
   8            stations
   9              census
   10           vehicles
```

So, why is this query working?

I think I am asking for rows from a table named `subways` with the `subway.name` in the SELECT portion of the query, isn't it true?

Comment: Have you run `\dt` from the same place you ran the query - i. e. psql?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was run both queries from `psql`. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM ...
     JOIN stations AS subways
    ...
```

This is called an [alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). You aliased `stations` as `subways`. So for the rest of the query (`ON`, `SELECT` part) the table is called subways and you can only reference it as subways.

Comment: doh. Thank you for your quick response!